# Disable CodeRush

Tags: .net, visual-studio, coderush, coderush-xpress, dxcore

I do not want to uninstall code rush. I just want to have the chance to turn it off when I don't want it.

Is this possible? (express version)...

Comment: Rory's answer did the trick for me. But if I disable it at startup to get it back on I had to go to Tools->Add In Manager and select DXCore to get the DevExpress menu back and then press load.

Comment: If I were you I'd report this to the Support Center ( http://www.devexpress.com/sc/ ) - Worth noting that whilst CodeRush xpress is Free ( to the end user). this is because Microsoft have licensed it on your behalf from DevExpress. As such it is fully supported as if you'd bought it yourself.

Comment: this is not an answer but adding to the question..excuse me for doing so).
 if we unload coderush will we get back the VS2010 keystrokes defaults.
( when I use some key combinations I get the conflict window to select wich one I prefer the VS or coderush.)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

First you should turn on the "DevExpress" menu. This is hidden by default in CodeRush Xpress.

See this blogpost http://www.coderjournal.com/2009/08/show-coderush-xpress-9-2-menu-in-visual-studio/

Once this is done you should be able to use the **Unload/Load** menu option (Last item on DevExpress menu)

Additionally you can set CodeRush Xpress to not load fully by default..

---

Follow these steps to get to the **Startup** options page:

1. From the DevExpress menu, select "Options...".
2. In the tree view on the left, navigate to this folder:

   Core
3. Select the "Startup" options page.
   This page level is Expert, and will only be visible if the Level combo on the lower-left of the Options dialog is set to Expert.

---

Once on this page, you can toggle the "**Load Manually**" setting to dictate how CodeRush starts.

Comment: +1: Amusingly, someone just +1'd my answer *after* this was posted without +1ing this!

Comment: This works. I noticed that when I set it not to load to get it back I had to go to Tools->Add In Manager and select DXCore to get the menu back.

Comment: Ruben that was me! I was just looking at the answers one at a time!

Comment: @AJM: Not that I'm not grateful for the +1, y'understand! I'll overlook you accepting Rory's arguably more complete answer in this instance :P

Comment: @AJM AFAIK if you disable using Addin Manager, that will superceed everything else. However it will require a restart to take effect. Once Enabled again in Addin Manager, then DXCore is loaded, but defers to the "Load Manually" setting to decide if to Load CodeRush... or something like that :) 

I do not work for DevExpress. I simple play with CodeRush.... a lot .... Yeah ok way too much to be healthy :D

Comment: Thanks a ton! Saves my time.. I don't even see that in Add-in manager and turning on that expert mode to see the startup page was the key!

Answer (score 8):

Shift Ctrl Alt O brings up CR's options dialog - not sure if there's something useful in the Xpress version though.

(In the Pro, the DevExpress menu has a "Unload" option)

Comment: I have the unload option in express as well. Just hadn't noticed it!

Comment: This confuses me a little... Where do you have the unload menu? Or was this after you enabled the DevExpres menu?

Answer (score 7):

In VS 2017 goto

> Tools > Extensions and Updates

Then you can enable, disable, uninstall the CodeRush or any other extension.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do not have any "Load Manually" checkbox in DevExpress Options,
but 2 checkboxes:
+ Re-register CodeRush commands with Visual Studio on next startup
+ Always re-register CodeRush commands on startup

VS2008
DXCore 9.1.3
ReSharper 5.1